# Syntax error: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

Tags: javascript, import, syntax, export

i'm trying to import a function from 'test.js' in 'index.js'

test.js:

```
var testFunction = function test(){ alert("hello World") }

export testFunction
```

in the very top of 'index.js' i tried the following statement:

```
import testFunction from './test.js'
```

now i've got the following error in my firefox console, when i'm running my index.html file in the browser:

SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module (in line 1)

Comment: What's the context? A browser? How exactly are the scripts being referenced?

Comment: Do you have `type="module"` set for the script element containing the import statement? Also, the import is importing a default export, but that can't be seen in the test.js file.

Comment: Yeah, i've got this error in my firefox browser console.

I have an index.html file:

```

Answer (score 11):

There's two ways:
**Solution 1(Default export)**:

test.js

```
var testFunction = function test() {alert('hello world')}

export default testFunction;
```

You can also do
`export default function() {alert('hello world')};`

index.js

```
import testFunction from './test.js'
```

**Solution 2(Named export)**:

test.js

```
var testFunction = function test() {alert('hello world')};

export { testFunction };
```

index.js

```
import { testFunction } from './test.js'
```

In both situations your html file has
`<script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>`

The above line rectifies the syntaxError: Import declarations may only appear at top level of module. It's because when you import, the file now becomes a module. Your index.js file is now the top-level module.

If you do this and get the Cross-Origin Request Block error. You should do your work through a server.

Further reading on [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules).

Answer (score 4):

#### Solution:

test.js

```js
var testFunction = function test(){ alert("hello World") }

export {testFunction}
```

index.js:

```js
import testFunction from './test.js'

//...
```

html:

```html
<script type="module" src="./index.js">
```

Comment: I tried this, but the moment I add type="module"  inside <script> as you mentioned above, i get this error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:x/y/z. (Reason: CORS request not http). Can you please help me out with this ? (I am getting this in Firefox and chrome as well)

Comment: that's another topic, your request is send from an adress which isn't the same adress where your server is running on... try to set request/response header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *