# Why am I getting "import declarations may only appear at the top level of a module" in my firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am developing a firefox extension and I would like to import a function from foo.js. My directory structure looks like this

```
app
  js
    foo.js
  content.js
  manifest.json
  background.js
```

foo.js

```
function myFunc() {
  let hello = 'hello from foo.js';

  return hello;
}

export {myFunc};
```

content.js

```
import { myFunc } from './js/foo.js';

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
  let result = myFunc();
  console.log(result);
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A notetaking tool for YouTube videos",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/border-48.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources":[
    "icons/my_icon.svg",
    "js/*"
  ]
}
```

background.js

```
browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
   browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {message: 'hello from background.js'});
});
```

This doesn't work. I get the following error in the console

```
import declarations may only appear at the top level of a module
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error in content.js, import is placed at the top of the file. I've tried some of the proposed solutions in this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59789622/syntax-error-import-declarations-may-only-appear-at-top-level-of-a-module) but this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to recommend anyone dealing with this issue to read over [Dhruvil Shah's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58137279/5348435) answer. They reccomend using a bundler like Webpack or rollup. I was able to use Webpack to bundle everything up into a single file called main.js. Then, I changed my manifest.json file from

```
  ....
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],
  ....
```

to

```
  ....
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["dist/main.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],
  ....
```

Also, [this video from fireship](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5IG4UmULyoA) on YouTube helped me used Webpack too.